Field strength renormalization in "Lattice QCD for novices" paper
In Lattice QCD for novices paper by P. Lepage, I came across eq. (46) at page 16, which is asked to prove. However, I couldn't derive it. This is my reasoning:

We know that $Z_2 = |\langle{0}|\phi(\vec{0},0)|\vec{p} = \vec{0}\rangle|^2$
We also know, by Lorentz transformations, that $\langle 0| \phi(\vec{x}, t)|\vec{p}\rangle = e^{i\vec{p}\cdot\vec{x}-iE_p t}\langle0|\phi(\vec{0},0)|\vec{p}=\vec{0}\rangle = e^{i\vec{p}\cdot\vec{x}-iE_p t} \sqrt{Z}$
Therefore $\langle 0 | \Gamma(0) |\vec{p}=\vec{0}\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_j^N\langle 0|\phi(\vec{x}_j, 0)|\vec{p}=\vec{0}\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_j^N e^{-im0}\sqrt{Z} = \sqrt{ZN}$
We also know that $\Gamma (t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_j^N \phi(\vec{x}_j, t)$ is the Fourier transform of the field operator with zero momentum, therefore when acting on $|0\rangle$ it creates a particle with zero momentum $|\vec{p}=\vec{0}\rangle = \Gamma(0)|0\rangle$
Therefore the quantity $\langle 0 | \Gamma(0) |\vec{p}=\vec{0}\rangle$ is just the norm of the state $|\vec{p}=\vec{0}\rangle$, which equals $2mN$.

From here I am not able to go on, so I'm definitely missing something. How do I solve this?
